# Conditionally render property object value?

Tags: javascript

I have this example function below:

```
const HelloWorld = (person, message) => {
      const { sender, message } = message
      const greeting = {
          to: person
          message: `Hi, ${sender} greets you. ${message}`
      };
      return sendMessage(greeting)
}
```

It works perfectly fine however message shows `null` if there's no value. How can I conditionally render values. `{message === null :` `Hi, ${sender} greets you.` : `Hi, ${sender} greets you. He said ${message}`}

Answer (score 0):

```js
const HelloWorld = (person, message) => {
      const { sender, msg } = message
      const greeting = {
          to: person,
          message: `Hi, ${sender} greets you.${msg ? 'He said '+ msg : ''}`
      };
      return greeting;
      // return sendMessage(greeting);
}

console.log(HelloWorld('Jack', { sender: "Joe", msg: "Test MSG" }));
console.log(HelloWorld('Jack', { sender: "Joe", msg: "" }));
```

You can simply use a ternary inside the string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator inside the template string, also note template strings can be nested:

```js
const HelloWorld = (person, msg) => {
      const { sender, message } = msg;
      const greeting = {
          to: person,
          message: `Hi, ${sender} greets you.${message ? ` He said ${message}`: ""}`
      };
      return greeting
}
console.log(HelloWorld("John Doe", {sender: "Jane Doe", message: null}));
console.log(HelloWorld("John Doe", {sender: "Jane Doe", message: "Howdy"}));
```